# What is the value of $\log5-\log9+\log10$

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

Sorry it might be a stupid question but I am confused why

$\log5-\log9+\log10=\log(50/9)$?
By bodmas rule first if we add then it should be $\log(5/90)$?

Comment: No. $\log5-(\log9+\log10)$ gives $\log\frac{5}{90}.$

Comment: Please use 
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
to format math on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\log 5 - \log 9 + \log 10 = (\log 5 - \log 9) + \log 10 = \log \frac{5}{9} + \log 10 = \log \frac{50}{9}$. Remember that the order in which addition and subtraction are done is from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log 5=\log\left(\frac{10}{2}\right)$$
$$=\log 10-\log 2$$
Therefore $$\log 5-\log 9+\log 10=2\log 10-\log 2-\log 9$$
$$=\log \left(\frac{100}{2\times 9}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(\frac{50}{9}\right)$$